# Python regex lookahead

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

trying to create a regex that finds some letter combinations follow by numbers.
Like ABC123, however the it could be ABC 123, ABCID:123

```
reg = re.compile('(ABC(?:ID\:| )?\d*?)(?:$| |,|\t)',re.IGNORECASE)
```

This works, however it also finds ABC by itself..

Is there way only find it if followed by numbers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `*?` quantifier with `\d`, and it matches **0** or more digits (as few as possible).

You may use

```
r'ABC(?:ID:| )?\d+'
```

or

```
r'[a-z]+(?:ID:| )?\d+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A46ysS/1)

**Details**:

- `ABC` - an `ABC` substring (or `[a-z]+` to match 1 or more ASCII letters (note that compiling the pattern with `re.I` flag will enable `[a-z]` to also match the uppercase ASCII letters, too))
- `(?:ID:| )?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of `ID:` or a space
- `\d+` - 1+ digits (the `+` is a greedy quantifier, so there is no need to define the right-hand context with `(?:$| |,|\t)` group).

Note that if you plan to also match Unicode letters in Python 2.x, you need to use

```
re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+(?:ID:| )?[0-9]+', s, flags=re.U|re.I)
```

The `re.U` flag will make `\W` and `\d` classes Unicode-aware.

Comment: Glad to help. Fixed the `[a-z]+` in the pattern (the description was fine).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
r"ABC(?:ID)?[ :]?\d+"
```

---

### [image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4kJZhh/1)

Comment: thanks, however I need the three letters to be the same